# Array.map() with input onChange always gets the last item on list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects in my state that I'm iterating through using `map()`. Each iteration has two tablerows inside a Fragment, with the second tablerow having an input tag that has an onChange() event that passes the current index to a function. I've noticed that it always passes the last index in the array.

```
{this.state.billingStatementData.map((row, index) => {
  return (
    <Fragment key={index}>
        <TableRow hover>
            ...
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TableCell>
            ...
              <input onChange={() => {
                    console.log(index);
                }}/>
              ...
```

Is it possible to get the current row or index of the iteration rather than the last item?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you create a Codepen?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-fast-l1rcc. I have an array of objects in the state. No matter which button you use to upload, it console logs the last id in the list

Answer (score 0):

Use props on *input*

```
<input index={index}...
```

And you can use this attribute in onChange.

Comment: I tried this, still doesn't work. Still passes the last value in the iteration.